# Changing column names when appropriate and ignoring in inapplicable

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I am trying to format datafile but my problem is some files have more variables included than others. I want to change the column names to fit my master datafile.

For example

```
df <- data.frame(
       f =c(111,123,128),
       w = c(99,84,102),
       s = c(122,105,112) )
```

Returns

```
    f   w   s
1 111  99 122
2 123  84 105
3 128 102 112
```

In order to rename the columns I did:

```
rename_df <- df %>% rename(Fall=f,Winter=w, Spring=s)
```

My problem is that some datafiles only come with Fall, some come with Fall and Winter, some come with all 3, or any combination you can think of. I am trying to figure out if there is anyway for R to look for "f", "w", "s" and when it finds one of those column names it changes it to the corresponding text ("Fall","Winter","Spring") and when once of the column is not present it just ignores it. I am trying to make a code that once a data file comes in I can run it through that code and it will return to me a df with the appropriate columns changed.

Thanks

Comment: Edited to avoid extraneous vectors in the workspace.  Fewer keystrokes but that is not the main reason for suggesting this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works even if `df` has a subset of the indicated column names:

```
L <- list(f = "Fall", w = "Winter", s = "Spring")
names(df) <- L[names(df)]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
newnames <- c(s="Spring", f="Fall", w="Winter")

df <- setNames(df, newnames[match(names(df), names(newnames))])

> df
  Fall Winter Spring
1  111     99    122
2  123     84    105
3  128    102    112
```